# How to install php IMAP for php5-fpm?

Tags: 12.10, php, imap, php-fpm

I'm trying to install Vtiger CRM on Ubuntu. This require IMAP. How to install PHP IMAP for `php5-fpm`?

Answer (score 20):

Carry out the following:

```
apt-get install php5-imap
```

However it's not enabled by default so enable it with:

```
php5enmod imap
```

Then bounce apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Done.

Comment: if using the php5-fpm service then must be "service php5-fpm restart"

Answer (score 4):

The `imap` library is in `php5-imap` and that applies to all sorts of PHP (cli, cgi, fpm, etc). To install:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imap
```